# Finite time involved In electron transitions

Tags: quantum-mechanics

From Wikipedia: "Atomic electron transition is a change of an electron from one quantum state to another within an atom. It appears discontinuous as the electron "jumps" from one energy level to another in a few nanoseconds or less."

Allowing for the above statement, is it correct (obvious?) to conclude that we can work backwards from, (1.) knowing the energy of the radiation emitted by some transition between any two separate energy levels of say, the H atom, through (2.) convert the energy into a frequency and then (3). invert this frequency to allow a time for the transition to be calculated?

Or is this a relatively easily and regularly performed measurement to do, with our current transition time calculation accuracy limited only by the precision of our energy measuring instrumentation? e.g is this the process used in an atomic clock?

The reason for this question is, although I could find out how an atomic clock works on Google, I want to go as far as I can on my own, without the easy (lazy?) answers. But also I don't want to waste anyone's time with questions that Google research will answer. If I could get this question confirmed, it's the best encouragement for more difficult problems. e.g. smolins "trouble with physics" popsci book mentions Unruh effect, but there is no explaination of any kind for it in his book. I'm happy thinking through explanations due to vacuum energy acceleration effects myself. This is what physics is all about, to me.

I ask this question just to get absolute confirmation that the idea of a quantum transition being irreversible and indivisible does not imply that these two properties also produce instantaneous transitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partial answer is no, you can't just invert the frequency: based on the following example.

The Lyman alpha transition in hydrogen from the $n=2$ to $n=1$ results in photons with a frequency of $\simeq 2.47 \times 10^{15}$ Hz.

The radiative lifetime of the transition is about 2 nanoseconds - i.e. it occurs with a frequency of about $5\times 10^{8}$ Hz.

The connection between the two is via the *width* of the spectral feature. i.e. In the absence of other broadening mechanisms, the Lyman Alpha line has a natural broadening of $\sim 5 \times 10^{8}$ Hz due to the finite transition rate and consequent energy uncertainty in the photon. The rate of the transition is determined by the strength of the electric dipole interaction between the initial and final states.

So what you would do is invert the *frequency width* of the transition to estimate the transition time (again, emphasizing that this is in the absence of other broadening mechanisms).

Comment: your response is much appreciated and i will need to go over your reply veeeerry slowly at my level of knowledge. I will need a bit of time to absorb your answer.

Comment: My basic question was could I get confirmation that transition is never  instantaneous. Based on your reply, can "The rate of the transition is determined by the strength of the electric dipole interaction between the initial and final states." be informally read as the difference between the  spin vector of electron in n = 2  and that of the spin vector of electron in n = 1  of final state (w.r.t its dot product with E of proton) has an influence on how fast transition occurs. If yes, my question is answered (it's not instanteous) and if no, I will just go over the basic principles again.

Comment: Saves you time and keeps me happy if you just reply yes or no. sorry for convolution, but I do have a genuine reason for asking it in ths way.

Comment: @irishphysics It's not instantaneous. But electric dipole transitions don't change the spin.

Comment: (a lot) more to think about so...question answered- much obliged